# The output of train_on_batch is batch_wise average or global average

Tags: python, tensorflow, keras

The output or `train_on_batch` of keras is the average of the current batch or global average of all trained samples?

Answer (score 0):

The `train_on_batch` function accepts a single batch of data, performs backpropagation, and then updates the model parameters. It uses single batch only and once.

Now to answer your question, Output of `train_on_batch` provides the training loss for that **current batch**.

You can refer below links for more description about same.

1. https://keras.io/models/model/
2. https://github.com/keras-team/keras/issues/10364